# Seeing dataframe attribute in VSCode Variable Explorer

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I recently started using VSCode for Jupyter Notebooks and so far it's great, but I have a custom object that stores pandas DataFrames and some other data as attributes. I was wondering, is there any way to see its attributes in the variable explorer? Right now the object just shows up with its type but there's no way to open it in the explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Within a Python Notebook, it's possible to view, inspect, sort, and filter the variables within your current Jupyter session. By selecting the **Variables** icon in the main toolbar after running code and cells, you'll see a list of the current variables, which will automatically update as variables are used in code. The variables pane will open at the bottom of the notebook.

[image]

For additional information about your variables, you can also double-click on a row or use the **Show variable in data viewer** button next to the variable for a more detailed view of a variable in the Data Viewer.

Comment: Issue is for custom objects the "Show variable in data viewer" option doesn't work, it just shows up in the list. For dataframes I create it works, but if that dataframe is an attribute of a custom object I can't see it

Comment: @rwalroth Could you provide some code for me to reproduce your situation? If there is no way to achieve it, I can propose it to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can create variables and assign objects' attributes to them. And view them regularly in the VSCode variables pane. Which is inconvenient, but still might be faster than using debug.

```
var_df = some_class.attribute_df
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing now, but was wondering if there's a better way. Might be a little niche of a use case

Comment: It would be very handy to have command like veiw(class.df) - to interact with variable viewer pane.